# Парсинг таблицы в список списков

Tags: python, парсер, xpath, grab

Добрый день.
Парсю страницу с помощью питоновского grab.
На странице есть таблица из нескольких десятков строк. Мне нужно спарсить оттуда информацию в список списков.

С xpath я знаком на самом базовом уровне.
Я хорошо представляю, как с его помощью получить коллекцию строчек; как из имеющейся строчки получить нужные мне ячейки. Вроде бы даже представляю, как получить коллекцию сразу всех ячеек таблицы.

Но мне-то нужно это всё положить в список списков, чтобы каждая строка в своём списке была.

Мне в голову приходит только взять коллекцию строк, перебирать их питоном в цикле, и для каждой строки делать отдельный xpath-запрос.

Насколько это хороший вариант? Есть ли какой-то более изящный путь?

Comment: можете указать URL, чтобы можно было попробовать?

Comment: @MaxU, например, вот отсюда http://kinozal.tv/browse.php я хочу спарсить таблицу с результатами поиска (в реальности в url будет подставляться ещё некий запрос, но это не принципиально, формат выдачи по конкретному запросу и без него одинаков.)

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант использующий Pandas модуль:

```
In [37]: import pandas as pd

In [38]: url = 'http://kinozal.tv/browse.php?s=%F7%E5%EB%EE%E2%E5%EA&g=0&c=0&v=0&d=0&w=0&t=0&f=0'
```

в следующей строке мы:

1. читаем (парсим) третью таблицу (по умолчанию `read_html()` парсит все таблицы и возвращает список DataFrames, нас интересует третья таблица [с индексом `2`]) по данному URL
2. пропускаем первую колонку (`Unnamed: 0`)
3. переименовываем колонку `Unnamed: 1` --> `Name`
4. сохраняем результирующий DataFrame как `df`

Code:

```
In [39]: df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[2].iloc[:, 1:].rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1':'Name'})
```

Показать первые 10 строк нашего "фрейма":

```
In [40]: df.head(10)
Out[40]:
                            Name  Комм.   Размер  Сидов  Пиров               Залит     Раздает
0  Джордж С. Клейсон - Самый ...      2   342 МБ      2      3     сегодня в 19:17       fx365
1  Последний человек на Земле...      1   1.9 ГБ     15     61     сегодня в 18:19    BLACKTIR
2  Последний человек на Земле...      2   707 МБ      8     35     сегодня в 18:18    BLACKTIR
3  Земфира - Маленький челове...      2  3.25 ГБ     25      8     сегодня в 17:15   Olyanchik
4  Фрунзик Мкртчян. Человек с...      2   500 МБ     23      0       вчера в 22:33   Человек91
5  Человек-невидимка (9 сезон...      4  4.85 ГБ      6     14       вчера в 22:29  Gorgona007
6  Борис Литвак - Тренинг лич...      3   142 МБ      7      1       вчера в 16:57       sekes
7  Человек из Ларами / The Ma...      1   744 МБ     20      0       вчера в 14:39  dushevnaya
8  Человек - швейцарский нож ...      0  1.46 ГБ     19      1  15.10.2016 в 21:34     Amancio
9  Земфира - Маленький челове...      1   243 МБ     53      1  15.10.2016 в 21:15     Amancio
```

вывести все строки в наименовании (столбец: `Name`) которых присутствует подстрока `'емфира'`:

```
In [41]: df.ix[df.Name.str.contains('емфира')]
Out[41]:
                             Name  Комм.   Размер  Сидов  Пиров               Залит      Раздает
3   Земфира - Маленький челове...      2  3.25 ГБ     25      8     сегодня в 17:15    Olyanchik
9   Земфира - Маленький челове...      1   243 МБ     53      1  15.10.2016 в 21:15      Amancio
14  Земфира - Маленький челове...     11  7.25 ГБ    228     13  15.10.2016 в 02:28       daboen
15  Земфира - Маленький челове...      4  2.38 ГБ     53      2  14.10.2016 в 20:29     DaDalida
16  Земфира - Маленький челове...      7  1.58 ГБ    172      4  14.10.2016 в 19:50  jaaadina123
```

список наименований, удовлетворяющих условию, в виде обычного списка:

```
In [43]: df.ix[df.Name.str.contains('емфира'), 'Name'].tolist()
Out[43]:
['Земфира - Маленький человек / 2016 / РУ / HDTVRip (720p)',
 'Земфира - Маленький человек. Концерт в Олимпийском / Рок / 2016 / MP3',
 'Земфира - Маленький человек / 2016 / РУ / HDTV (1080i)',
 'Земфира - Маленький человек / 2016 / РУ / DVB',
 'Земфира - Маленький человек / 2016 / РУ / SATRip']
```

PS вообще при помощи Pandas можно делать много интересных вещей (особенно это касается обработки данных) с минимальными затратами (минимум кода) с практически максимальной (для Python) производительностью.